# Coefficient Extraction of Products of Generating Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, power-series, generating-functions

### Is there an easier way to extract coefficients from the product of two generating functions?

In Levin's book, the only way mentioned was $${a_0}{b_0} + ({a_0}{b_1}+{a_1}{b_0})x + (a_0b_2+a_1b_1+a_2b_1)x^2...$$ and so on.

It's hard when the sequence does not have a definite pattern. Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as the "[cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)", and as far as I know it is the only way to do it. However, it's not as complicated as it looks.

The $n$th coefficient of $x^n$ in $AB$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{i+j=n} a_i b_j$. That is

$$a_0b_n + a_1b_{n-1} + \ldots + a_{n-1}b_1 + a_nb_0$$

Notice each product sums to $n$:

- $a_0 b_n$ is $0+n = n$
- $a_1 b_{n-1}$ is $1 + (n-1) = n$
- and so on

In this way, knowing the first $n$ coefficients of $A$ and the first $n$ coefficients of $B$ is enough to know the first $n$ coefficients of $AB$.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks! I was just trying to confirm, because the books don't dig much.